# Inability to populate an html table with json response from an api call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have tried a few variations of the below code to populate an html table with json data. I have limited the api response to 1 in an attempt to simplify. The json data seems to be heavily nested, but I have little idea of how to actually parse and display the data. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? As a start, I only wanto to display the "name".

Here is the response:

```
{"list":[{"id":31,"name":".Scala_Test_Player 0696GS (RMS09061606)","uuid":"a363ef6c-4ea0-4835-bd98-03b27e9139fc","previewPlayer":false,"enabled":true,"mac":"00-00-00-00-00-00","type":"CHROMEBOX","distributionServer":{"id":2,"name":"Main","driver":"IP_P2P"},"playergroups":[{"id":2,"name":"GameStop","numberOfPlayers":24}],"playerDisplays":[{"id":31,"name":"Display 1","channel":{"id":51,"name":"Test Channel 2 videos"},"screenCounter":1}],"requestLogs":false,"downloadThreads":1,"unusedFilesCache":24,"planDeliveryMethod":"CONTENT_MANAGER_DIRECT","pollingInterval":1,"pollingUnit":"MINUTES","logLevel":"normal","metadataValue":[{"id":551,"value":"12","playerMetadata":{"id":18,"name":"Player.ScreenOnOff_Model","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"PICKLIST","order":2,"predefinedValues":[{"id":7,"value":"SONYFWD-40LX2F","sortOrder":1},{"id":8,"value":"NECLCD4215","sortOrder":2},{"id":10,"value":"PANASONIC","sortOrder":3},{"id":11,"value":"PHILIPS","sortOrder":4},{"id":12,"value":"SAMSUNG","sortOrder":5}]}},{"id":457,"value":"21:15","playerMetadata":{"id":10,"name":"Player.ScreenOff_Wednesday","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"ANY","order":11}},{"id":548,"value":"09:00","playerMetadata":{"id":12,"name":"Player.ScreenOn_Monday","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"ANY","order":6}},{"id":455,"value":"21:00","playerMetadata":{"id":7,"name":"Player.ScreenOff_Sunday","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"ANY","order":5}},{"id":546,"value":"09:05","playerMetadata":{"id":11,"name":"Player.ScreenOn_Friday","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"ANY","order":14}},{"id":547,"value":"21:15","playerMetadata":{"id":4,"name":"Player.ScreenOff_Friday","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"ANY","order":15}},{"id":453,"value":"100","playerMetadata":{"id":2,"name":"Player.ChromeVolume","datatype":"INTEGER","valueType":"ANY","order":3}},{"id":456,"value":"09:05","playerMetadata":{"id":17,"name":"Player.ScreenOn_Wednesday","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"ANY","order":10}},{"id":550,"value":"13","playerMetadata":{"id":25,"name":"Player.Screen_Input","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"PICKLIST","order":24,"predefinedValues":[{"id":15,"value":"DP","sortOrder":1},{"id":16,"value":"DVI","sortOrder":2},{"id":34,"value":"HD15","sortOrder":3},{"id":13,"value":"HDMI1","sortOrder":4},{"id":14,"value":"HDMI2","sortOrder":5},{"id":17,"value":"PC","sortOrder":6}]}},{"id":549,"value":"21:05","playerMetadata":{"id":5,"name":"Player.ScreenOff_Monday","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"ANY","order":7}},{"id":454,"value":"00:00","playerMetadata":{"id":14,"name":"Player.ScreenOn_Sunday","datatype":"STRING","valueType":"ANY","order":4}}],"usedPairingKey":"R3Y4N2","active":"HEARTBEAT_OVERDUE","lastModified":"2016-12-20 18:26:27"}],"offset":0,"count":36}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody id="scalaapi">
<tr><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
function jsonData()
{

$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"https://avacmd25.scala.com:44335/ContentManager/api/rest/players?limit=1&offset=0&sort=name",
    datatype:'json',
    success:function(data)
    {
        var jdata=$.parseJSON(data);
        $(function(){
            $.each(jdata,function(i,item){
                var tr = $('<tr>').append(
                $('<td>').text(list.name),              
            $("#scalaapi tbody").append(tr));
            })
        })

    }
})
}
```

Comment: There is no `list.name` here `$('<td>').text(list.name)`. It might be `item.name`

Comment: I tried item.name first, it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your are implementing `.append` in a wrong way and selection `tbody` also seems wrong.

If you have proper response as stated, try this in your `success` callback

```
success: function(data) {
  var list = data.list;
  $.each(list, function(i, item) {
    var tr = $('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(item.name)); //taking name
    $("#scalaapi").append(tr);
  });
}
```